# Hierarchical Database Structure SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have Different hierarchical structure

Please find Below structure.

```
 1. Parent 1

    1.1 Child 1

    1.2 Child 2

    1.3 Child 3

            1.3.1 Child 4


            **1.3.2 Parent 2**
```

Now Look at above tree, here child can also have sub child as PARENT.

So how can I achieve this, keep in mind that I want whole tree without for each loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDMBS? How many nodes? What is the maximum depth?

Comment: 1) Does it metter? 2) N number of nodes 3) up to nth level.

Comment: Yes, it does matter. Some RDBMS support recursive queries, others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, two approaches may fit your needs.

Version #1: The most obvious (but slow) attempt is to simply create a table holding each node and a reference (foreign key) to its parent. A parent of NULL indicates a/the root node.

The disadvantage of this attempt is that you either need a loop (what you want to avoid) or a RDBMS with the possibility to define and execute recursive queries (usually with a CTE).

Version #2: The second attempt would be the choice in the real world. Whereas the first solution is able to store unlimited depth, these scenarios usually don't occur in hirarchical trees.

Again you create a table with one row per node, but instead having a reference to the parent, you store the absolute path to that node within the tree in e.g. a `VarChar` column, just like the absolute path of a file in a filesystem. Here, the 'directory name' corresponds to e.g. the ID of the node.

Version #1 has the advantage of being very compact, but it takes quite an effort to prune the tree or retrieve a list of all nodes with their absolute path (RDBMS are not very good in recursive structures). On the other side, a lot of UI components expect exactly this structure to display the tree on screen. Questions like 'Which nodes are indirect childs of node X' are both slow and quite difficult to answer.

Version #2 has the advantage of making it very easy to implement tree manipulation (deletion, pruning, moving nodes and subtrees). Also, the list you require is a simple `SELECT`. The question 'show all direct or indirect childs of node X' are answered with a simple `SELECT` as well.
The caveat is the increased size due to redundant saving of paths and the limited depth of the possible tree to save.